# Django won't render form in multiple templates?

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

New to Django.  Crispy form renders beautifully on register page.  Exact copy and paste doesn't render the form on login page?  All help is greatly appreciated.

I've also tried removing Crispy from the equation with no luck.

main_project/urls.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import path, include
from  users import views as user_views
from website import views as website_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('register/', user_views.register, name='register'), 
    path('home/', website_views.home, name='site-home'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name='logout')
]
```

users/forms.py

```py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    address = forms.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

users/views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import UserRegisterForm

# Create your views here.
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        register_form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if register_form.is_valid():
            register_form.save()
            username = register_form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            email = register_form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            messages.success(request, f'Account created for {username}')
            return redirect('website-home')
    else:
        register_form = UserRegisterForm()
        return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'register_form':register_form})
```

users/register.html AND users/login.html

```py
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<!-- Extra Styling? -->
{% block extrahead %}
{% endblock extrahead %}

<!-- Include Navbar? -->
{% block navbar %}
{% include 'navbar.html' %}
{% endblock navbar %}

<!-- Main HTML Page Cotent -->
{% block content %}

<div class="container">
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-6">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <legend>
                        {{register_form|crispy}}
                    </legend>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <div class='row justify-content-center'>
            <div class="col-6">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success float-right">Register</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you have copied the template. What are you trying to achieve? In any case the login view won't send the registration form to the template.

Comment: I appreciate the reply.  I think I'm confused on how to send the `UserRegistrationForm()` to the `login.html` template.  I've copied the 'register.html' template to the `login.html` template just as a starting point (since it worked on the `register.html` template).  I guess I need to create a separate form for the `login.html` template, add a `def login()` function to the `views.py`, and pass that form to the `login.html`?  I'm confused because I've been following Corey Schafer's video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3aVqWaLjqS4&t=501s) and he doesn't do any of this?

Comment: But it worked in the register.html template because that is rendered by the register view. The login.html template is rendered by LoginView, which you don't control since you import it from django.contrib.auth. I'm not sure why you want to do this though, login.html is for showing the login form.

Comment: Your response came in before I could edit my above response.  Please see above.  Thanks.

Comment: No if you just want to show the login form you don't need to do any of that; you just use `form` instead of `registration_form` in the template since that is what LoginView sends.

Comment: **WOW** the simplest thing.  Thank you very much!  Would you be willing to help me understand how I could have sussed that out?  When I look at the Django Docs (which are generally very good) for [LoginView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView) it's very unclear to me what it returns?  I guess the sample code provided is supposed to be the big hint?  I feel like I'm missing a fundamental piece of the puzzle here.

Comment: It's documented there under "This template gets passed four template context variables:".

Comment: Not my day today... my eyes skipped right over that.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel Roseman solved this perfectly, see the comments.

Basically, the above is sort of a mess. Django class `ListView()` already returns a form to the template of your choosing (that's sort of the point).  Using `form` instead of `register_form` for the form tag makes everything work perfect.  See corrected code below.

`users/login.html`

```py
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<!-- Extra Styling? -->
{% block extrahead %}
{% endblock extrahead %}

<!-- Include Navbar? -->
{% block navbar %}
{% include 'navbar.html' %}
{% endblock navbar %}

<!-- Main HTML Page Cotent -->
{% block content %}

<div class="container">
        <form>
            <fieldset>
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <legend>
                            {{form|crispy}}
                        </legend>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div class='row justify-content-center'>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success float-right">Register</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

{% endblock content %}
```